# applying functions to dynamic content javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I'm trying to start/stop a setInterval function by changing the id of an element and applying two different functions to the different id's. here's the code at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seq
  $('#start').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('id','stop');
     seq=self.setInterval(function(){blah()},125);
  });
  $('#stop').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('id','start');
     clearInterval(seq);
  });
});
```

when I click the #start element, the setInterval starts and the id changes to #stop, but if I click again (on the element now called #stop), the code for #start is carried out (another setInterval is added)
thanks

the function 'blah' is just an example of a made up function

Comment: Where is your `beat` function?

Comment: Those event hooks won't work for dynamic content since jQuery is building the event pool for elements that exist at first load. Dynamic content comes after document.ready.
And why are you changing the id anyways? This is generally bad practice unless you REALLY have to.

Comment: Events don't magically re-bind when the id changes.  You're better off just binding to a single event handler, then using an `if` block to figure out which state it's in.

Answer (score 5):

When you say:

```
$('some selector').click(...
```

That binds a click handler to all elements that match `some selector` *at that moment* - it doesn't automatically apply to elements that might match it in future.

To have the handler apply to elements that match the selector at the time of the click event you need to use a delegated event handler, which means attaching the handler to a parent element (or to `document` if the element has no static parent):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seq
    $(document).on('click', '#start', function(){
        $(this).attr('id','stop');
        seq=self.setInterval(function(){blah()},125);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#stop', function(){
        $(this).attr('id','start');
        clearInterval(seq);
    });
});
```

The [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) lets you attach "normal" non-delegated handlers or delegated handlers depending on the parameter you pass to it.

The other option is to *not* change the id and just use a single click handler that tests the current state in some manner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seq;
  $('#start').click(function(){
     if (seq) {
        clearInterval(seq);
        seq = null;
     } else
        seq=self.setInterval(function(){blah()},125);
  });
});
```

Comment: The second solution is the much better one, but are you sure that it shoudn't say seq = false ? I am not sure at the moment if seq = null is enough...

Comment: I had a look, I did not know but javascript sees false, 0, "", null and undefined as falsey, so sorry for doubting...

Comment: @m70 - Sure, you could use `false` if you like. I used `null` because to me it seemed more like the natural opposite of a valid and current interval id (not that interval ids are actually pointers or anything, they're just numbers). But I didn't bother initialising `seq` to `null` before the click handler because I'm lazy and as you now know `undefined` is also falsey.

Answer (score 1):

I would NOT change the id since this will not change the event bindings. You generally should never change an elements id tag. The better plan (at least to me) is to set it as a class. Then use html data tags to decide what the state is.

`<button type="button" class="buttonClass" data-state="start">Button Text</button>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seq
  $('.buttonClass').click(function(){
     var state = $(this).data('state');
     if(state=='start') {
         //do start interval stuff
         seq=self.setInterval(function(){blah()},125);
         $(this).data('state','stop'); //Change the state now
     } else if(state=='stop') {
         //do stop interval stuff
         clearInterval(seq)
         $(this).data('state','start'); //Change the state again
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: like that better than my solution because of using the data attribute instead of a class...

Comment: It can be made even simpler if you use the existing `seq` variable as the state indicator (see my answer).

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean there. Much simpler. I just generally do things in a class fashion in case I need to re-use it, so relying on one variable isn't generally my first go to.

Comment: Sure, sometimes classes and/or data attributes are best. In this case, for example, changing the class could maintain state _and_ provide automatic update of the colour of the button, perhaps green for start and red for stop. (Not that the OP expressed any such requirement - I'm just putting the idea out there.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check for the state like this (no need to add event listener to document):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seq;
    $('#start').on('click', function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('running')){
            seq=self.setInterval(function(){blah()},125);
            $(this).addClass('running');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('running');
            clearInterval(seq);
        }
    });
});
```